# Modify date to -7 days in .csv file via shell script

Tags: shell, text-processing, date

I have a file with records in this format  :

```
D20200826,S2927,977,1
```

Expected output :

```
D20200819,S2927,977,1
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is if somehow I can get the date (first column) to be moved 7 days in the past, i.e. if current date is 29, I want it to be 22.

Comment: Use the `date` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `awk` has time-related functions `mktime()` and `strftime()` (`mawk` or GNU `awk`), then the `awk` script

```c
BEGIN {
        OFS = FS = ","
}

{
        t = mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00",
                substr($1,2,4),
                substr($1,6,2),
                substr($1,8,2)));

        $1 = substr($1,1,1) strftime("%Y%m%d", t - 7*24*60*60)

        print
}
```

would break apart the date specification in the first comma-delimited column using multiple calls to `substr()` and create a Unix timestamp with `mktime()`.

It would then decrease the generated timestamp by exactly seven days (in seconds) and re-format it as a `YYYYMMDD` date string using `strftime()`.  The generated date string, along with the first character of the first column's data (a `D` in the example) is then assigned to the first column before the whole modified line is printed.

Testing the above script on some data:

```
$ cat file
D20200826,S2927,977,1
D20200106,S2927,977,1
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
D20200819,S2927,977,1
D20191230,S2927,977,1
```

---

A slightly shorter variant:

```c
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }

{
        $1 = substr($1,1,1) strftime("%Y%m%d",
                mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00",
                        substr($1,2,4),
                        substr($1,6,2),
                        substr($1,8,2))) - 7*24*60*60)
}

1
```

And, as a "one-liner":

```
awk -F, '{ $1 = substr($1,1,1) strftime("%Y%m%d",mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00",substr($1,2,4),substr($1,6,2),substr($1,8,2)))-7*24*60*60) }; 1' OFS="," file
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify future dates only in this file ? Basically I have many records in file with current date and future dates. So if possible can only records having future dates change to 7 days before ?

D20200908,S2927,977,1
D20200908,S2927,977,1
D20200908,S2927,977,1
D20201108,S2927,977,1
D20201108,S2927,977,1
I would want only the last 2 records get changed to D20201101,S2927,977,1. If that's something achievable

Answer (score 0):

Only for gawk

```
awk -F, '{$1 = strftime("D%Y%m%d",\
mktime(gensub(/.(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})/, "\\1 \\2 \\3 0 0 0", 1, $1))-7*3600*24)}1' OFS=, file
```